# Unity3d Android - Fixed Resolution

Tags: unity

How can i set a fixed 720p resolution on any devices using unity3d android?

> unity3d version: 2018.4.5f1

Comment: Presumably you considered setting up a RenderTexture with those dimensions and rendering to/displaying that?

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen.SetResolution.html

Be careful with the aspect ratio of the screen, use something like this:

```
 Vector2Int newResolution = Vector2Int(720, Mathf.RoundToInt(Screen.height * 720 / Screen.width));
 Screen.SetResolution(newResolution.x,newResolution.y, true);
```